How to properly use Google OAuth Tokens (id_token, access_token, refresh_token) with Firebase in a React App?"
I have read a lot of articles that teach how to implement OAuth login (in my case, Google Login with Firebase). However, I have a problem with the access_token. Here is my approach:

Log in with Google in the frontend (React app) using Firebase, and get the id_token, refresh_token, and access_token (aka google_access_token, what I'm concerned about).
Store the id_token in cookies because it only lasts for one hour, and store the refresh_token in localStorage.
Send the id_token with each request to the backend. If there is no id_token in the cookies (e.g., if the user deleted it or it expired), then renew it using the refresh_token (this step still occurs in the frontend).
The backend verifies the id_token; if it's valid, the backend only sends back the requested data. If the id_token is invalid, the frontend triggers a logout and clears all tokens.

My approach doesn't use the access_token. Here are my questions:

IIRC, the id_token should not replace the access_token, which means my backend needs an access_token, right?
People also say that the google_access_token should only be used to interact with Google APIs, so what access_token do I actually need? Should I create my own, or use the access_token I got in step 1?
If I have to create my own access_token, then I'll have 4 kinds of tokens (id_token, refresh_token, google_access_token, and my_own_access_token). Is that correct?


RE: "what access_token do I actually need?" - Please edit your question to include the list of APIs you intend to authenticate against (or at least some of them). This will allow other readers to identify what token is to be used where and if the Firebase-issued token (generated from the underlying Google authorization) can be used for that purpose.
